How to add icons to the dropdown array list in Android Kotlin?
I have this code to control the dropdown array list in a Fragment using Kotlin.
How can I add icons in each item list programmatically (as shown in the picture).
Can someone please help me if this is possible. Thanks!
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.foodField.setAdapter(
            ArrayAdapter(
                requireContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                resources.getStringArray(R.array.food),

Here is the array:
<string-array name="food">
        <item>Pizza</item>
        <item>Bread</item>
    </string-array>



You would replace android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item with a custom layout that has your text and icon, and replace ArrayAdapter with a custom adapter that uses that layout.
